# UK DATV - Evidence that your sponsor is not, or will not be, in breach of UK immigration laws at the time of your visit

Tags: visas, uk, datv

I'm in Indian citizen and am applying for a UK DATV for traveling New Delhi -> London Heathrow -> Barbados. The visa application form at the end has a list of documents that I need to check to progress the application.

One of the confusing documents is-

> Evidence that your sponsor is not, or will not be, in breach of UK immigration laws at the time of your visit

My trip will be funded by a US company I work with and they have no presence in the UK.

This is a required document and it doesn't allow to skip this document.

[image]

What am I supposed to submit for this document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the section that checkbox is under states:

> You can also send in this/these document/s to help support your application

Note the “you ***can*** also…”, its not mandatory to do so, its a suggestion - you are just ticking the box to affirm that you know to provide them if you need to, not that you must provide them.

Only the documents in the top section are mandatory.

Tick the box, move on.

Comment: do you happen to have done this personally?

Comment: @HarshilSharma Im a British citizen, so no, but also being a native English speaker Im confident in my interpretation of your screenshot.  Only the first section is mandatory, the rest of the list is advisory only.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @DJClayworth that isn't technically possible, look again at the screenshot, with error message at the top.

Comment: I withdraw my comment.